# Fortran 77 with BLAS - can't figure out how to compile

Tags: compilation, blas, fortran77

I'm trying to get BLAS working with in a FORTRAN 77 program, but so far I've been unsuccesful and I can't figure out how to get going with this. For reference I'm doing this under Ubuntu 12.10.

This is the code of the program I'm trying to compile:

```
program blastest
  implicit none
  include 'cblas_f77.h'

end
```

The file `cblas_f77.h` resides in `/usr/include`, and there are both `libblas.a` and `libblas.so` (and a bunch of other BLAS related files) in `/usr/lib`.

How do you configure this to work properly?

#### So far, I've tried the following:

Note: adding `-lblas` to either of the options make no difference at all...

Just `f77`, no options (didn't really expect this to work, but what the heck...):

```
 $ f77 blastest.f -o blastest
    MAIN blastest:
Cannot open file cblas_f77.h
/usr/bin/f77: aborting compilation
```

`f77` with include option to find the header file. Now, instead it fails on (despite the file name) not being coded with FORTRAN 77 in mind, so the first six columns are nonempty...

```
$ f77 blastest.f -o blastest -I/usr/include
       MAIN blastest:
    Error on line 1 of /usr/include/cblas_f77.h: nondigit in statement label field "/*   "
    Error on line 2 of /usr/include/cblas_f77.h: labeled continuation line (starts " * cbl")
    Error on line 3 of /usr/include/cblas_f77.h: labeled continuation line (starts " * Wri")
    ...
```

Full output: http://pastebin.com/eZBzh9N5

Switched to `gfortran`, to be more flexible with the spacing in the header file:

```
$ gfortran blastest.f -o blastest -I/usr/include
   Warning: cblas_f77.h:9: Illegal preprocessor directive
   Warning: cblas_f77.h:10: Illegal preprocessor directive
   Warning: cblas_f77.h:12: Illegal preprocessor directive
   ...
```

Full output: http://pastebin.com/P71Di9pR

OK, so I guessed I need `-cpp` to get the preprocessor working. That gave exactly the same output as above. Also, if you keep reading you see that the full output, the compiler is still complaining about labelled continuation lines further down...

Comment: Did you even look at `cblas_f77.h`? It is not fortran. It is a C header. Including C headers in fortran source gives errors. Nothing unexpected there, so don't do it.

Comment: @eriktous: I did look at it, but I didn't scroll far enough to realize it contained more than just `#define` directives, which I assumed the preprocessor would take care of regardless of the language of my source files... Do you have any suggestions on how to get BLAS working with FORTRAN?

Comment: You didn't have to scroll that far. The first line is a C comment line, which is illegal in fortran. Since BLAS is written in F77, you might try just referencing the procedures, perhaps writing some `external` and return-type declaration statements.

Comment: @eriktous: I incorrectly assumed the comments would also be taken care of by the preprocessor... That aside - I don't know how to use the `external` keyword and Google gives me lots of noise; would you mind showing me?

Comment: Ah, you may be right on the preprocessor taking out comments. I hardly ever use it, so I didn't think about that; but as you said: that aside - `external` statements may not be necessary. (I mainly work with module procedures, so don't have to use it myself very often. I'm not exactly sure when it's required for external procedures and when not.) Have you tried simply referencing the BLAS procedures you need? You have to specify the type of the functions you use, but other than that you can probably use them like any other external procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are using the C library "cblas". I would recompile with this command:

```
gfortran blastest.f -o blastest -L/usr/lib -lblas
```

and this should sort it all out. I do not believe (though i am not sure) that you need to make use of the "include" statement.

Comment: That gives a variant of the first error: "blastest.f:3: Error: Can't open included file 'cblas_f77.h'". Adding the include statement again takes me back to the same output as above.

Comment: I should also note that I am not particular about *which* BLAS-incarnation I use - to start with, I just want to get BLAS working, and there was only four matches for `sudo find / -name "*blas*.h"` on my machine: "cblas.h", "cblas_f77.h" and 32/64-bit versions of blas.h under MATLAB...